# Find the name of the branch which sold the most

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to combines data from 3 tables in one query that will let me find out the name of the branch that sold the most (in order to practice nested queries) This problem has no significance in the real world.

This shows which employee is assigned to which branch in a table called "employee"

| emp_id | branch_id |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 101 | 1 |
| 102 | 2 |
| 103 | 2 |
| 104 | 2 |
| 105 | 2 |
| 106 | 3 |
| 107 | 3 |
| 108 | 3 |

This shows how much each employee sold (table is "works_with")

| emp_id | total_sales |
| --- | --- |
| 102 | 267000 |
| 102 | 15000 |
| 105 | 55000 |
| 105 | 33000 |
| 105 | 130000 |
| 107 | 5000 |
| 107 | 26000 |
| 108 | 22500 |
| 108 | 12000 |

This shows which branch has which name (table is "branch")

| branch_id | branch_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Corporate |
| 2 | Scranton |
| 3 | Stamford |

I found a way to see how much each branch sold.

```
SELECT e.branch_id, SUM(w.total_sales)
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN works_with w
ON e.emp_id = w.emp_id
GROUP BY e.branch_id
ORDER BY SUM(w.total_sales) DESC;
```

| branch_id | branch_name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 500000 |
| 3 | 65500 |
| 1 | undefined |

Here I found what the branch_id of the branch that sells the most is.

```
SELECT e.branch_id
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN works_with w
ON e.emp_id = w.emp_id
GROUP BY e.branch_id
ORDER BY SUM(w.total_sales) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

| branch_id |
| --- |
| 2 |

Now I needed to find the name of that branch, sounds easy enough right? Not for me, apparently. Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT branch_name
FROM branch
WHERE branch_id IN (
    SELECT e.branch_id
    FROM employee e
    LEFT JOIN works_with w
    ON e.emp_id = w.emp_id
    GROUP BY e.branch_id
    ORDER BY SUM(w.total_sales) DESC
)
LIMIT 1;
```

This gives me "Corporate" as the name, when it should give me "Scranton", as it is the one that sold the most. Apparently it's because ORDER BY in subqueries doesn't do anything or something. I think this means I have to start over, or transfer ORDER BY to outside the IN thing.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` needs to be in the subquery, not the main query; the order of the subquery doesn't make the main query use that order. But MySQL doesn't allow that when the subquery is used with `WHERE ... IN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't over-complicate your solution; all you need is an additional `JOIN` to the `branch` table and an adjustment to the field you're `SELECT`ing and `GROUP`ing `BY`:

```
SELECT branch.branch_name
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN works_with w
ON e.emp_id = w.emp_id
LEFT JOIN branch
ON e.branch_id = branch.branch_id
GROUP BY branch.branch_name
ORDER BY SUM(w.total_sales) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Result:

| branch_name |
| --- |
| Scranton |

[<sup>DB Fiddle</sup>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rYo3KWaL7m8XmUd7DSF6Q8/0)

Comment: Thanks, this works... I was too mentally drained to figure this out myself I guess, and badly wanted to forget about this problem, since it took me a few hours to come to my conclusions.

Comment: there is no need for a Left Join s INNER JOIN suffices